# Php If statement not working as expected

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

I am making an email script in php. What happens is a mysql query is made, and the output of this is stored in the following strings :

```
$personal1 = $userinfo->salutation;
$personal2 = $userinfo->surname;
$business = $userinfo->businessname;
```

Next I have an if statement, this checks to see if the surname is blank, if it is, it then substitutes the salutation + surname with the business name. The problem I am having is that the emails keep being sent out with Dear, Business Name , even if the surname field is not blank, I am not sure what I am doing wrong with the following code for it to do this though ?.

```
if ($personal2=="") {
$name = $business; }
else {
$name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;};
```

EDIT >>>>>>>>>>

If I echo out the contents of the strings I get :

```
personal1 = Mr
personal2 = Johnson
business = Hat Trick Media
```

Edit 2 >>>>>>>
This is some of the code, it is then passed onto the mailer.

```
<?php
$cf_uid = $_GET['token'];
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addupdatelead WHERE cf_uid = '$cf_uid'") or die(mysql_error());
$userinfo = mysql_fetch_object($query);

$personal2 = $userinfo->surname;
$personal1 = $userinfo->salutation;
$business = $userinfo->businessname;
?>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM hqfjt_chronoforms_data_addemailtemplate");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    echo '<tr class="table-row">';

   echo '<th class="template-name">';
   echo '<div class="namerow">';
   $id = $row->cf_uid;
   $form_id = $row->form_id;
   $query = mysql_query("SELECT `$form_id` FROM email_history WHERE cf_id = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());
$datesent = mysql_fetch_object($query);
$date = $datesent->$form_id;

if ($personal2=="") {
$name = $business; }
else {
$name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;};
```

Comment: There could be many reasons why, simply because the information you have provided is not sufficient enough to answer your question specifically.

Comment: Have you dumped or echod $userinfo->surname to make sure it contains what you expect it to?

Comment: Show us an example of the content of the $personal2 variable. Make sure to get it from just before the if statement.

Comment: provide a reproducible code so that we can test it

Comment: Show the result of var_dump($personal2);

Comment: ok, I have echo'd out the contents of all three and added it to my question

Comment: Try using `if (empty($personal2)) {` instead of `if ($personal2=="") {`

Comment: @Iain Simpson   It looks like you have to show the whole code (after your "if") - you are messing up somewhere else. Can be easily checked by echo $name; just after your "if" block

Comment: The `while` section does not have a closing bracket. Also you should check the query `$query = mysql_query("SELECT $form_id FROM email_history WHERE cf_id = '$user_id'") or die(mysql_error());` because I'm not too sure about your column name `$form_id`. Also you should try to keep queries outside of loops whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

Is your code a valid statement? Your code structure is awful. Instead of...

```
if ($personal2=="") { 
$name = $business; } 
else { 
$name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;};
```

Use

```
if ($personal2=="") { 
    $name = $business;
} 
else {
    $name = $personal1 . ' ' . $personal2;
}
```

You seem to have an extra ; that you dont need.

You also dont seem to close the while loop in the code you posted...

Comment: I know my coding is bad, I have only been coding for 3 weeks that's why its a bit sketchy :-S

Comment: The closing of the while loop is not included in that code above but it is in the original, I just realised I missed it off.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have found out what the problem was, $name was coming in the session from the previous page and overwriting $name on this page, I have now set it to destroy the session before it loads this page and it seems to have sorted it now, thanks for everyone's help :-)

Comment: Instead of destroying the session it's better to disable register_globals.

Comment: If session information affects variables on the current page then my guess would still be that register_globals is switched on. Did you check the state inside the current script?

Comment: No, but when I do phpinfo it says it is off.

Comment: If phpinfo says it is off then I can't explain why information from the previous page would affect variables on the current page.